# Instantiate a class that extends an abstract class that implements an Interface

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

So I have this class called COL that contains the following function:

```
public class CatalogueOfLife extends EDITPlatform {

private static final String nomatchfound = "there is nothing";

protected String getNoResultsMessage(){
      return COL.nomatchfound;
}
```

And then an Interface called *interface* that has this function:

```
public interface WSInterface {

public boolean matchfound(String noMatchString);
}
```

Finally an abstract class called *platform* that uses both functions as follow:

```
public abstract class EDITPlatform implements WSInterface{

public boolean matchfound(String noMatchString){
   if (noMatchString.contains(getNoResultMessage())){
        return true;
   }
   return false; }
```

Now I would like to invoke the `matchfound` function from a main function. I can only use a *COL* object, but the issue is that I need to have more than just one class to extend the platform.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand where is the issue... Why can you only use a `COL` object ? Why do you need to have several classes extends `Platform` ? Do you want to do something like `COL col = new Platform();` then be able to do `col.matchfound(aString)` ?

Comment: Because I actually will be having other classes other than COL that will extend the abstract class. so for example, I will have `WAP` and `COL` Both extending `platform`.. and each will send a different `nomatchfound` string to the `platform` function.. I need to call the function from the platform in the main, without having to specify explicitly what sub-class called it.

Comment: I seriously doubt that your interface is called `interface` as you say, because that's a Java reserved keyword. Please post the real class and interface declarations rather than describing them in English; that also tells us what your class hierarchy looks like.

Comment: the interface is called "WSInterface".. The hierarchy is the following: `COL extends platform`  // `platform implements interface`

Comment: Could you add a main with the issue? I don't see the problem so I think I don't get your question. If WAP and COL extends Platform you could have a collection of Platform objects and call obj.matchFound(input)... something like Platform[] platforms= {new WAP(),new COL()}; for each(platform:platforms){platform.matchFound("some string")}

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** your problem is that `EDITPlatform` doesn't have `getNoResultMessage()` method. So you can't call it.

if you need to define that method inside `CatalogueOfLife` then you should use an abstract method:

```
public abstract class EDITPlatform implements WSInterface{

    protected abstract String getNoResultMessage();

    public boolean matchfound(String noMatchString){
        if (noMatchString.contains(getNoResultMessage())){
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    }
}
```

And then override it in the solid class

```
public class CatalogueOfLife extends EDITPlatform {

    private static final String nomatchfound = "there is nothing";

    @Override
    protected String getNoResultsMessage(){
        return CatalogueOfLife.nomatchfound;
    }
}
```

Finally

```
CatalogueOfLife col = new CatalogueOfLife();
boolean matched = col.matchFound(myString);
```

Comment: Actually, it's COL that is a subclass of Platform!

Comment: why don't you post your classes and interface declarations

Answer (score 0):

If COL is a subclass of Platform, then in the code

```
if (noMatchString.contains(getNoResultsMessage()))
```

`getNoResultsMessage()` is not accessible in Platform.

And since you have implemented all methods of the interface in `Platform`, it need not be `abstract`

Is this what you are looking for:

```
class CatalogueOfLife // extends EDITPlatform
{
    private static final String nomatchfound = "there is nothing";

    protected String getNoResultsMessage() {
        return CatalogueOfLife.nomatchfound;
    }
}

interface WSInterface {
    public boolean matchfound(String noMatchString);
}

class EDITPlatform extends CatalogueOfLife implements WSInterface {
    public boolean matchfound(String noMatchString) {
        if (noMatchString.contains(getNoResultsMessage()))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EDITPlatform plat = new EDITPlatform();
        System.out.println(plat.getNoResultsMessage());
        System.out.println(plat.matchfound("there is nothing"));
    }

}
```